# links, tags a not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 links on the site, they work, but if you log in from your phone, they stop working, tag a.

```html
<section class="section section--map" id="map">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="map">
                    <h2 class="map__title">
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="https://dayz.xam.nu/" target="_blank">
                            map dayz
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
```

there is also a problem with the second link

```html
<div class="container__header">
            <div class="header__inner">
                <div class="header__logo" data-scroll="#intro"></div>
                    <nav class="nav" id="nav">
                        <a class="nav__link active" href="#" data-scroll="#about">about</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#services">howtoplay</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#mods">mods</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#updates">updates</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#" data-scroll="#map">map</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="https://dayzmsk.dayzplay.ru/" target="_blank">shop</a>
                    </nav>
                <a class="btn__discord" href="https://discord.gg/qyUnGSePWf" target="_blank"><img src="../img/dslogosite.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

almost all links work on js, fast and smooth transition to the section

```js
document.querySelector('.nav').addEventListener("click", (event) => {

    if (event.target.getAttribute('href') !== '#') {
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    let elementOffset = 0;

    let parent = document.querySelector('.nav');
    let menuItem = parent.querySelectorAll('.nav__link');

    if(event.target.classList.contains('nav__link')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {
            menuItem[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }

    let elementId = event.target.getAttribute('data-scroll');
    let element = event.target;

    if(elementId && element){

        elementOffset = getElementScrollOffset(elementId);

        scrollToTop(elementOffset);

        element.classList.add('active');
    }
});
```

I tried to give index 999 to elements, tried to remove the target, but it didn’t help, I don’t understand why it works on the computer, but not on the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display block was to blame, if you remove it from the element, everything works. Close.